# How to update span element in HTML with javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update a span element to show my javascript variable is this correct?

```js
var hometown = "Indianapolis" ;
document.getElementById('hometown').innerHTML = 'Indianapolis';
```

```html
Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: You can also use `textContent` if you're only updating text.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: This works. If it is not working for you, perhaps it is your browser. innerText is another similar to innerHTML.

Answer (score 3):

It is basically correct except that you never use your variable, so there is no point to the variable. If you want to use the variable to change it you can do this instead.

```js
var hometown = "Indianapolis";
document.getElementById('hometown').innerHTML = hometown;
```

```html
Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span>
```

With this code, you can have a text input that gets set to the variable `hometown`, like this.

```js
function update() {
var hometown = document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("hometown").innerHTML = hometown;
  }
```

```html
Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span>
<br>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" onClick="update()" value="Update">
```

I know this one is a little complicated, but it works, and it's all your code.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely. You are not using the variable.

```
document.getElementById('hometown').innerHTML = hometown;
```

Since you are not setting html content, using `.textContent` property is a better option:

```
document.getElementById('hometown').textContent = hometown;
```

Also make sure that element is added to DOM before selecting it, i.e. put the script after the target `span` element.

```
Hometown: <span id="hometown"></span>
<script> /* JavaScript code goes here */  </script>
```